# Performing a function after the href has loaded when an a tag is pressed (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add content to a css grid when a certain a tag is pressed, but when I click on the `a` tag nothing happens when the page loads.

Ive tried multiple things such as adding a setInterval() and waiting for the css grid to load before executing the code, here is the code:

```
$(".il2").click(function() {
    var productGridClass = document.getElementsByClassName("productGrid");
    productGridClass.onload = function() {
            for(var i = 0; i < womenArray.length; i++) {
                    $("<img class='pBox' src='' alt='products'> </img>").appendTo(".productGrid");
            }
    $(".pBox").attr("src", "assets/grid-button-image.png");
    }
})
```

the expected result is when the a tag is pressed the page loads and the content for the css grid loads

HTML

```
<li><a class="link il2" href="product-page.html">MENS</a></li>
```

Comment: Please share html code too

Comment: "<li><a class="link il2" href="product-page.html">MENS</a></li>" i have 3 of these

Comment: I think the `onload` trigger may not be firing in your use case.

Comment: Do you have the option to do it with ajax instead? That would make it a lot easier. Now you load a new page, so the script of the original page stops.

Comment: I cant do it with ajax, need to follow specification

Comment: @phant0M you will need to store it somewhere that the button is pressed then (cookie, localstorage, GET parameter, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what elements in your HTML have the class `productGrid`, but it doesn't matter, for the following reasons:

1) `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements. You can't just set `onload =` on this collection, you need to loop through them and set it on each element.

2) Even if you did this, just setting `onload` on an element doesn't do anything. You would want to use `addEventListener`, or use jQuery's event handlers.

3) Even if you fixed that, the `onload` event *does not fire* for individual elements in the page. It only fires once, when the entire document is loaded.

I'm not sure why this code is even inside the wrapping `click()` event handler, I would remove it and just replace it with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for(var i = 0; i < womenArray.length; i++) {
    $("<img class='pBox' src='' alt='products'> </img>").appendTo(".productGrid");
  }
  $(".pBox").attr("src", "assets/grid-button-image.png");
});
```

This is assuming you wanted the code to run when the document loads. If you actually want it to run after you click something, then put it inside the click handler instead (but don't wrap it in *both*).

Comment: thanks for your help, i have 3 a tags and depending on which is pressed it will load a certain amount of content for the css grid, for example the first a tag should put 8 images into the grid and the second a tag should put 9 in, this is why its wrapped in a click() handler as i need to execute different code for each a tag, so i need to find a way to wait for the product page to load from clicking one of the a tags and then fill the grid with content